# Append the value in bootstrap model using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

These is my javascript function i want to append the SEARCHID in my bootstrap model form.
How to i get that id in my bootstrap model form

These is my bootstrap model hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="ID" id="searchid">
```

This is my javascript function in these function i get my id when user click on button

```
function searchitem(id)
{
    var SEARCHID = id;
    console.log(SEARCHID);
}
<a class="btn btn-primary text-capitalize ct-js-btnEdit--Agents  btn-sm" id="<?php echo $DETAILS->id;?>" value="<?php echo $DETAILS->id;?>" onclick="searchitem(this.id);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: try this html :<a class="btn btn-primary text-capitalize ct-js-btnEdit--Agents  btn-sm" id="<?php echo $DETAILS->id;?>" value="<?php echo $DETAILS->id;?>" onclick="searchitem(<?php echo $DETAILS->id;?>);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution, comments added to explain the process

```js
//on button click
$("#yourPHPId").on("click", function() {
  //get the id from the button element
  var searchId = $("#searchid").attr("id");

  //append to modal-body (inside p tag if preferred)
  $(".modal-body p").append("Hidden field id = " + "<b>" +  searchId + "</b>");
});

//on modal hide
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  //empty the modal body (<p>) contents
  $(".modal-body p").empty();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="ID" id="searchid">

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button !-->
<!-- Insert your PHP functions here as required, they have been taken out in order for the code snippet to work !-->
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yourPHPId" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i> Edit</a>

<!-- Modal !-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content !-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```